# Get string from string array in php

Tags: php

I have a string `$string = 'contact['.'firstname'.']';`

How can I get the `contact` and `firstname` from that string.

Sorry about my English, It's hard to describe the question

Comment: Please give an example of the string and the parts you want to extract from it..

Comment: How can I get the `contact` and `firstname` from that string. maybe an array

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$result = explode(chr(91),substr($string,0,-1));
```

then `$result[0]` and `$result[1]` will have what you want

Comment: PHP not allowed you to explode with "[", it's a special character

Comment: not even   $result = explode(chr(91),$string); sorry i didn't know that and on manual i haven't seen it

Comment: I still got `Error: Parse error on line 2:
    [0] => contact    [1] =
--------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'`

Comment: OK it work find after I run `$string = substr($string, 0 , -1);`

Comment: consider to accept or/and upvote an answer if it was helpful

Comment: Sorry I am not enough reputation for do that

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = 'contact['.'firstname'.']';
$a = explode('[',substr($string,0,-1));
echo $a[0];
echo '<br />';
echo $a[1];
?>
```